# Is it okay for a layout to have both onTouch listener as well as Gesture listener?

Tags: android, touch, gesture

Hi all in my android app I move objects on screen as per user input.
Basically I have to take care of two inputs - drag and UP(touch & remove)

So I implemented Gesture listener where the two methods - 
`onScroll()` & `onSingleTapUp()` were used to handle these two input events.

But `onSingleTapUp()` does not work if the user has kept her finger for a long time on screen and then lifted it up.

So the conditions now require me implement `onTouch` to harness the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` functionality.

But would it be a good idea to use both `onTouch` & Gesture Listener.

Or should I shift my code to onTouch and remove gesture listener ?